# Display Dropdown list items in the combobox on hover

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a `combobox list` and I want to display the hovered item of the `dropdown list` in the `combobox`.

[image: Image Link]

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xqk34.png)

In the above image, if I hover on the Truck, the `combobox` text should display as truck, same way with car and bike. Any help appreciated.

Sample Code:

```
       var carTypes = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        carTypes.Add(1, "Car");
        carTypes.Add(2, "Truck");
        carTypes.Add(3, "Bike");
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
        comboBox1.DataSource = carTypes.ToList();
```

Comment: Are you  using the standard WinForms ComboBox, or the DevExpress ComboBoxEdit? The latter does not have a data source; you would need to use the DevExpress LookUpEdit control instead.

Comment: can you add the image to stackover , This site can’t be reached i.stack.imgur.com refused to connect.

Comment: Brendon: I am using Windows Forms ComboBox.

Comment: Anyone to help?